# How to retrieve the physical files from different git branches?

Tags: git

If I create a git branch (or more), it does not create a physical directory in my file system. Does this mean all my actual code is stored in the secret .git folder?

What if I would need a physical copy of all the files in my "working" branch and my "master" branch?

Comment: `git show <branch>:path/to/file`

Comment: A branch is not a folder, a branch is a reference to a commit

Comment: The physical files in your project are updated/changed everytime you switch branches.  Git is not a file-based version control system.

Comment: Yes, that concept is slowly dawning on me. But my question is what if I would want a physical copy of both my working branch and my master branch? (If only to back them up as physical files without a git folder).

Comment: Have a look at my answer.  Just do a `git checkout` of the branch whose files you want to backup, and then backup the files of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if I would need a physical copy of all the files in my "working" branch and my "master" branch?

I think the easiest thing for you to do would be to simply checkout each of the branches and then take a backup of the project directory, or the portion which you want.  So for the `master` branch you could do `git checkout master`, and then take a snapshot of the local files of interest.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant. (a way to retrieve the actual files for different git branches).

Comment: It's not allowed yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

To get files from another branch into the working tree use:

```
git checkout <branch_name> -- <paths>
```

Example:

```
git checkout feature-a -- filename.cpp
```

If you want to join two or more branches together use:

```
git merge <branch_name>
```

If you are on the master branch and want to continue the work on another branch use:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```